# Can you use the Form() command in ActiveAdmin in the content of a custom page?

Tags: activeadmin

I've got a custom page defined in ActiveAdmin, like so

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page "Configure Account" do

page_action ....

content do
  panel "Your Account" do
    #render :partial => 'customer_edit'
    form(:autocomplete => "off", :url => admin_configure_account_path ) do |f|
      f.semantic_errors *f.object.errors.keys

      f.inputs "Customer Details" do
        f.input :name
      end
      f.actions
    end
```

Notice the commented out "render partial".

If I use that, i get a form that looks correct on the page and basically operates as I'd expect it to, but I have to have the partial form file in the views folder.

However, if I try to use the

```
 form() do |f|
```

syntax, I get errors that indicate that f.actions is an undefined method, that f.object.errors is undefined, and that f.inputs is undefined.

Any idea whether using the form() function is even supported in the content block of a custom page like this? It might not be, but I've found some mentions floating around that seem to imply it is.

Comment: In your case `form` is an https://github.com/gregbell/arbre method, not rails helper. To use rails helper it's better to render a partial, like you commented it.

Comment: Yeah, for "pages", I never did find any cleaner way. I'd have rather been able to describe forms via the arbre syntax but the partial works. Maybe in the next AA version.